# std::string operator[]

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++, неопределённое-поведение

Пробую запустить такой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    std::string b("a");
    std::cout << b[20];
    return 0;
}
```

ожидал увидеть какой-то мусор в ответе, но в итоге это вешает VS(или начинает
долгую загрузку символов для combase.dll) если запустить с отладчиком. А если без то получаю Debug Assertion Failed. Как я понял из документации [] не должен проверять выход за границы. Тогда почему компилятор не может выполнить эти операции? Или т.к это undefined behavior, то стандартный компилятор VS решает эту проблему так?

Comment: Он именно *НЕ ПРОВЕРЯЕТ*, а потому и пропускает обращение з пределы выделенной памяти. А как решает это VS - так у вас какое-то представление странное, что если вы нарушите правила движения на дороге, то обязательно воткнетесь именно в дерево - а не в столб или пешехода - мол, Бог решает UB именно так...? :)

Comment: @Harry, но это вывод одного символа. Либо падай с segfault'ом, либо выводи мусор, но зацикливаться-то не на чем же?

Comment: @Harry, тогда не понятно почему в случае с массивом мы выводим мусор, а не падаем точно также.

Comment: Это UB. Непредсказуемо. Два разных запуска программы могут дать разные результаты. Тем более что просто массив - в стеке (если это локальная переменная), а в `string` - память где-то в куче...

Comment: "VS решает эту проблему так" Что значит "решает так"? И какую "проблему"? Компилятор никак тут ничего даже и не пытается решать. И не видит никакой "проблемы". Он вообще ничего не делает, по принципу "будь что будет". В вашем случае получилось так.

Comment: данный код не может повесить студию. посмотрите настройки (ну или дайте студии прогрузить символы первый раз)

Comment: Кстати, в отладочной версии как раз оператор может выполнять проверку выхода за границу, и генерировать какое-то неперехвачиваемое (некем) исключение...

Comment: @goldstar_labs, да вы были правы. Нужно было дождаться загрузки(просто не всегда появлялось окно)

Comment: @Harry, на самом деле ошибка идентичная, что с отладкой, что без. А именно Debug Assertion Failed. Сейчас пройду в файлик и посмотрю, что ее генерирует.

Comment: Debug Assertion Failed в релизной конфигурации не будет. Априори ставлю на то, что в отладочной проверяется выход за границы диапазона...

Comment: @Harry, вроде VS2010 страдала тем, что вектор в релизе поверял диапазон? Так что может от версии студии зависеть. Но в новой, вероятно, такое уже выпилили.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в VS2017 действительно нет этой ошибки в релизе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Извините, что тут, но комментария мало...

QED - вот:

```
_NODISCARD reference operator[](const size_type _Off)
    {   // subscript mutable sequence
    auto& _My_data = this->_Get_data();
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 1
    _STL_VERIFY(_Off <= _My_data._Mysize, "string subscript out of range");
#endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 1 */
    return (_My_data._Myptr()[_Off]);
    }
```

из `<xstring>` в VC++ 2017 - вот тут и вылетает в отладочной версии, на проверке выхода за границы диапазона. В релизе этого не будет...